# .htaccess запрет доступа к файлам txt

Tags: .htaccess

Как запретить из браузера доступ к файлам `*.txt`?
Перепробовал следующие варианты, но ни один из них не сработал (к остальным файлам не `txt` запрет работает):

```
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all

   Deny from all

    <FilesMatch "\.txt$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    </FilesMatch>
```

Comment: `txt` - нужно обернуть в скобки - `.(txt)$` - точку экранировать не обязательно в данном случае. Но лучше оставить только те, которые нужны форматы, а остальные будут недоступны.

Comment: этот вариант я тоже пробовал, не сработал

Comment: Не понятна проблема, раз работают другие, то и это должно работать, одно дело, если `apache` над `nginx`, то тут уж только через `location` самого `nginx` нужно запрещать ибо бывает, что `apache`. дальше корневой директории не видит.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так можно запретить доступ ко всем `txt` на сервере

```html
<FilesMatch "(\.(txt)|~)$">
  Order allow,deny Deny from all Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
```

после этой манипуляции при вызове в адрессной строке любого файла `txt` получим вот такую ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не понимаю почему, но это тоже не срабатывает на моем сервере, txt файлы все равно показываются

Comment: у вас точно apache или может nginx ??

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том что у меня nginx, отключил обработку файлов txt и все заработало